# Maximum Width of Binary Tree - Java code

Tags: java, queue, iteration, binary-tree

Below is the question:

Given a binary tree, write a function to get the maximum width of the given tree. The width of a tree is the maximum width among all levels. The binary tree has the same structure as a full binary tree, but some nodes are null.

The width of one level is defined as the length between the end-nodes (the leftmost and right most non-null nodes in the level, where the null nodes between the end-nodes are also counted into the length calculation.

And here is my code:

```
public class MaxWidth {
    public int widthOfBinaryTree(TreeNode root) {
        Queue<TreeNode> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        queue.offer(root);
        int maxWidth = queue.size();

        while (! queue.isEmpty()) {
            int size = queue.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                TreeNode rootCur = queue.poll();
                if (rootCur.left != null) {
                    queue.offer(root.left);
                }
                if (rootCur.right != null) {
                    queue.offer(root.right);
                }
            }

            if (queue.size() > maxWidth) {
                maxWidth = queue.size();
            }
        }

        return maxWidth;
    }
}
```

However, this ends up with an endless loop~       I don't know why?  Thanks!

Supplement:   The input tree structure is:

```
               1
           3        2
         5   3        9
```

Comment: What happened when you tried debugging?

Comment: try stepping through your code with a debugger

Comment: Could you please share the input tree structure as well ?

Comment: When I was debugging, looks like some elements would never be removed from the queue.      As a result, the queue size is getting bigger and bigger~    But I don't know why this happens~

Comment: Look carefully at the code--this is a simple typo.

Comment: Do not add information in comments, [edit] your post.

Comment: ?? Where is the "simple typo"? Any hint? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (rootCur.left != null) {
    queue.offer(root.left); ==> Change root to rootCur
}
if (rootCur.right != null) {
    queue.offer(root.right); ==> Change root to rootCur
}
```

You are adding the elements from root.left and root.right and hence, the queue never gets exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
if (rootCur.left != null) {
    queue.offer(root.left); // this is not rootCur!
}
if (rootCur.right != null) {
    queue.offer(root.right); // this is not rootCur!
}
```